# how can you express "keyof T" to be a subset of String?

Tags: typescript

The Firebase typings have an interface `IQuery` which has the `equalTo()` method typed as:

```
public equalTo(value: number | string | boolean | null, name?: string): IQuery;
```

I have a mocking library which is trying to mimic the API surface of what Firebase is exposing but in the case of the `name` parameter the general typing of "string" can be made more specific:

```
 public equalTo(value: number | string | boolean | null, key?: keyof T): IQuery<T>
```

By stating `keyof T` we get some very useful static checking that I'd hate to lose out on and in fact up to TypeScript 2.8.3 I seemed to be able to do this but when moving to `2.9.x`+ of Typescript I now get this error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.

For a bit more context, the class definition in my mocking library is:

```
 export default class Query<T = any> implements IQuery<T> { ... }
```

Where the `<T>` generic type is an indicator of type of the data structure that the query will return.

Further it is worth noting that T, *will always* be shaped as a dictionary/hash with string keys and therefore `keyof T` will subset of string values but in my typing I'm not making this clear so I get where Typescript is taking issue ... I just don't know how to express that `keyof T` must be a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is related to a change in the way `keyof` works in 2.9, until 2.9 `keyof` only returned `string` keys, from 2.9 onward it will return `number` and `symbol` keys. This is the reference for [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#updated-keyof)

To only accept `string` keys you can use `Extract<keyof T, string>` as the type for the `key` parameter, or if you want to revert to the old behavior you can use the `--keyofStringsOnly` compiler flag

```
public equalTo(value: number | string | boolean | null, key?: Extract<keyof T, string>): IQuery<T>
```

Comment: @ken, not just `Extract<T,U>` but [its friends too](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types).

Comment: `Extract<keyof T, string>` works like a charm - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can also require keys in your type to be string-only:

```
key?: keyof T & string
```